# Как при hover изменить цвет иконки svg

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 22 31" enable-background="new 0 0 22 31" xml:space="preserve">
  <image id="image0" width="22" height="31" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAfCAMAAADUZc3BAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN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"/>
</svg>
```

Пробовал сделать так, но эффекта это не дало:

```css
svg:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас использован svg файл формата base64, который в силу своих особенностей не поддается стилизации стандартными способами.

Выход один,- использовать фильтры SVG для окраски.

*Например фильтр красного цвета:*

```css
#image0:hover {
filter:url(#RedFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 22 31" enable-background="new 0 0 22 31" xml:space="preserve">
 <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" width="32" height="32">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
</defs> 
  <image id="image0" width="22" height="31" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAfCAMAAADUZc3BAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN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"/> 


 
</svg>
```

**Фильтр синего цвета**:

```css
#image0:hover {
filter:url(#BlueFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="22px" height="31px" viewBox="0 0 22 31" enable-background="new 0 0 22 31" xml:space="preserve">
 <defs>
 <filter id="BlueFilter" width="32" height="32">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
</defs> 
  <image id="image0" width="22" height="31" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAfCAMAAADUZc3BAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJN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"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: @Vlad467 Если ответ был вам полезен, отметь его пожалуйста, чекбоксом и плюсом

Comment: если Svg вставлен с помощью <img> работать будет?

Comment: @Vlad467 да, будет

Comment: сделал так и при hover просто пропадает

Comment: @Vlad467 Добавьте код, пожалуйста в ваш вопрос, как через <img> добавляли svg файл в html/ Как сделаете это я проверю на своем сервере

Comment: <img src="t1.svg" alt="">

Comment: @Vlad467 с путями до сервера всё нормально или проверяли на локалке?

Comment: на локалке. Я так понял если добавлять через img то он не видит dom дерева Svg

Comment: @Vlad467 заглядывайте почаще, разберусь в ближайшее время Тут просят перейти в чат. У нас есть специализированный чат по svg присоединяйтесь https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Answer (score 1):

**В вопросе автора не было слов, как добавить `svg` файл формата `base64`**
поэтому, чтобы не смешивать всё в одну кучу оформляю отдельный ответ.

Провел некоторые исследования, хочу поделиться: 
браузеры всё время совершенствуются и постоянно появляются "приятные" сюрпризы.

Способ добавления файла `svg` c помощью команды `<img>`

- Работает  на локальном ПК, но не стилизуется с помощью svg фильтров

  `<img src="t1.svg" width="100px" height="100px" alt="image description">`
- точно также и при вызове с сервера, добавляется файл `*.svg` в
  `html`, но не работают команды `SVG` фильтров для раскрашивания
  элементов svg

*Получается, что остался только один рабочий способ добавления svg файлов - с помощью команды `<object>`*

Ниже  пример вызова одного и того же файла `t1.svg` с сервера двумя разными командами и добавления его в `HTML`

```css
img1 {
font-size:18px;
}
.obj1 {
font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<p class="img1">  Add &lt;img&gt; </p> 
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/t1.svg" width="50px" height="50px" alt="image description"> 
<p class="obj1">  Add &lt;object&gt; </p> 
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/t1.svg" width="50px" height="50px" > </object>
```

Из примера видно, что стилизация работает только при добавлении svg файла с помощью команды `<object>`

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от самого SVG нужно подобрать подходящий файл

```css
svg {
  fill: red;
}

svg:hover {
  fill: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path d="M256,0C167.641,0,96,71.625,96,160c0,24.75,5.625,48.219,15.672,69.125C112.234,230.313,256,512,256,512l142.594-279.375
  C409.719,210.844,416,186.156,416,160C416,71.625,344.375,0,256,0z M256,256c-53.016,0-96-43-96-96s42.984-96,96-96
  c53,0,96,43,96,96S309,256,256,256z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а зачем вам десяток тегов `g`?=)))